# Bash script fault creating mdadm array

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, raid, mdadm

I am working on a script to create md1 array, first to check if the array exist if not it will create it. I get command as command mdadm not found and a few others. The script wont run.

```
 #!/bin/bash
check="proc/mdstat | grep md1"

 if [ -e $check]; then
{
echo "MD1 is already here"
}
    else 
{
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sdf1 <<EOF
yes
EOF
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo  "MD1 was created"
elif [$? -ne 0]; then
    echo "A fault has occured"
fi
}
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `check` variable is completely wrong. It's assigning the literal string `"proc/mdstat | grep md1"` to `check`.

To fix it, use this instead:

```
if grep -q -e 'md1:' -e 'md127:' /proc/mdstat; then
    echo "MD1 is already here"
else 
    if echo yes | mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sdf1; then
        echo  "MD1 was created"
    else
        echo "An error has occurred"
    fi
fi
```

A few other notes:

- Bash doesn't mandate braces for multi line statements, so it's often cleaner to omit them. You should always ensure proper indentation, though.
- Bash's `if` statement doesn't require a `[ .. ]` construct. It can use any command; if the command exits with 0, it's considered true, else false.
- The `<< EOF` syntax is redundant, a simple `echo yes |` will do that.

Comment: Thank you! I get error: mdadm command not found. EDIT: need to install mdadm again - will tell you if it worked.

Comment: I have a question, sometimes it creates md as md127. Is it a way to check for both md1 and md127 then create it if none of these exist?

Comment: @user3185936: See my edit. It will search for either md1 or md127, and it will create md1 if none exist.

Comment: Thank you! I have another question. How can I check if these disk already is partioned? 
for d in sdc sdd sde sdf; do
fdisk /dev/$d << EOF

n
p
1


t
fd
w



EOF
done

Comment: @user3185936: Feel free to [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: Thanks: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422535/check-if-disks-already-is-partioned-if-not-partion